# AEC3 suppress NearEnd audio when FarEnd has Noise

Tags: webrtc, chromium, aec, echo-cancellation

I use Chromium's AEC3 for Acoustic Echo Cancellation for my application . Echo Cancellation works fine . But whenever a noise played in speaker , NearEnd audio ( voice from My Microphone ) suppresses .

I uses the default configuration used here https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/refs/heads/main/api/audio/echo_canceller3_config.h

SampleRate : 48k

My code :

```
     speaker->CopyFrom(&input,*config);
     speaker->SplitIntoFrequencyBands();
     echo->AnalyzeRender(speaker);

     mic->CopyFrom(&input,*config);
     mic->SplitIntoFrequencyBands();
     echo->AnalyzeCapture(mic);       
     echo->ProcessCapture(mic,false);
     mic->MergeFrequencyBands();
     mic->CopyTo(*config,&output);
```

is there anything i am doing wrong or need to change any configuration ?.

Any help would be appreciable , Thanks in Advance .

Comment: What do you mean by "a noise played in speaker"? It sounds like you might have echo suppression working in the background. Mobile devices, for example, often have hardware echo suppression integrated. This mechanism turns the microphone off when there are loud sounds from speaker.

Comment: a noise played in speaker - > Actually We are implementing RealTime Audio Communication through websocket , where we faced echo issue , We successfully integrated aec3 into our project , But Voice from Microphone is suppressing when we get noise from other person in the call  and issue occurs only when using aec3

Comment: So if sound from speaker is relatively loud you do not capture anything from the microphone? That sounds like echo suppression at work. What kind of devices are you using? Did you try on different devices?

Comment: Yes , We tried all the OS ( windows,mac,linux ) , Issue occurs on all the platforms ,Looks like an issue only in aec3 algorithm